# Check if the 2 textbox is null and display an error message

Tags: javascript

I was trying to validate the two textbox if they are null or not. 
I have two textbox and 1 span where the error message displays. 
Here is my html

```
    <div id="manual_input_container" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
#1&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="numeric"  id="first_value[]" name="first_value[]" maxlength="8" size="5" placeholder="First"> 
<span name="get_operator "id="get_operator"></span>
<input type="text" class="numeric" id="second_value[]" name="second_value[]" maxlength="8" size="5" placeholder="Second">
<span name="errorOrganizer1" id="errorOrganizer1"  class = "errorMsg"></span> &nbsp;</div>
```

This is my javascript

```
var first_value = document.getElementsByName("first_value[]");
var second_value = document.getElementsByName("second_value[]");
var err1 = document.getElementsByName('errorOrganizer1');
var isTrue = true;

    for(var i=0; i<first_value.length; i++)
          {
              if(first_value[i].value == "" || isNaN(first_value[i].value))
              {
                first_value[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f6d9d4';
                err1[i].innerHTML = "Invalid";
                isTrue = false;
              }

              else if(second_value[i].value == "" || isNaN(second_value[i].value))
              {
                second_value[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f6d9d4';
                err1[i].innerHTML = "Invalid";
                 isTrue = false
              }

              else 
              {
                first_value[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
                second_value[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
                err1[i].innerHTML = "";


              }
          }
          return isTrue;
```

Error message is not displaying correctly here. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using id like an array (second_value[])?

Comment: to check NULL simply use : `if(first_value[i].value)`

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior yeah,. that's already on my script, I was just asking if how can I display an error message on 1 span, checking the two input text.

Comment: @user3627265 See my answer below

Comment: I guess you must use class name instead of the name array. BTW does your background color change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK It is easy one I did'nt saw it:

**Change the line below:**

```
err1[i].innerHTML = "Invalid";
```

**To**

```
err1[i].innerText = "Invalid";
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6Eu7A/

Comment: From the Code I guess he has n numbers of such HTML structures and is using a forloop for them. But still that this answer is correct.

Comment: @SSS yes Only to get Element i think getElementById("someid") is the straight way to do.

Comment: He must have class name instead of same name and loop through all elements of that class name.

Comment: This is correct, but I was having a problem on the changing of background color. They seems not working on some cases.